# Facebook like-button won't count

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I thought I'd add a like-button of my Facebook-page to my website. 
After two hours of trying, I'm just about to give up. 
I've added this to the head of my website:

> < meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.homesuitehomefilm.nl/" />
>   < meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
>       < meta property="fb:admins" content="hoeveeltekensmagjeeigenlijknoueenheleboelkennelijk" />

The last one (fb:admins) is my personal FB username. Took me a while to figure out what I should fill in there. I guess this is correct, since it's the only query that doesn't cause an error on the FB debugger.
Still, the like-button doesn't show a number of likes:
[image]

No matter how I mess with the code, it's displayed exactly the same.
I can't even get the black text (it's there behind the button, hard to see) to change. CSS won't have any effect on it. 
Is there any easy way to add a simple like-button to my website? I figured this was so supposed to be sort-of-easy, since I've seen more of them around. But this is probably the hardest thing i've ever come across.

Comment: My website: www.homesuitehomefilm.nl     
My facebookpage: www.facebook.com/hshfilm     (stackoverflow won't let me make hyperlinks, sorry)

Comment: the like button looks fine to me. maybe just a cache problem?

Comment: _“I guess this is correct”_ – don’t “guess”, **check**: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ Currently your implementation has errors.

Comment: I kind of gave up on the normal approach, but it turns out there's a much easier way, using iframes. That works! (Found it on http://blog.woodylabs.com/2011/08/facebook-like-button-not-working-or-showing-0-likes/)   I used the debug tool for a while. I know my site still has errors, but I've tried everything and haven't been able to fix it. It's just too complicated for me, just like the rest of the Facebook interface. But the Like button works, so I'm sort of satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the code as documented by Facebook?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

You already have this code at the top of your source

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then just add the following

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/hshfilm" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```